# Error in creating .so file from .o files generated using multiple .c files

Tags: c, atmel, libusb-1.0

I have created the .o file as follows,

```
*gcc -I/home/vineeshvs/Dropbox/wel/workspace/Atmel -I /home/vineeshvs/Downloads/libusb-1.0.9 -I /home/vineeshvs/Downloads/libusb-1.0.9/libusb/ usb_comm.c hex2bin.c hex_read.c crc32.c -o vs.o -lusb-1.0*
```

Then I used the following command to get .so file

```
*gcc vs.o -shared  -o libhello.so*
```

Then I am getting error as follows

```
*vs.o: In function `__i686.get_pc_thunk.bx':

(.text+0xaa6): multiple definition of `__i686.get_pc_thunk.bx'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbeginS.o:crtstuff.c:

(.text.__i686.get_pc_thunk.bx[__i686.get_pc_thunk.bx]+0x0): first defined here
vs.o: In function `_fini':

(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
vs.o: In function `__data_start':

(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbeginS.o:(.data.rel+0x0): first defined here
vs.o: In function `_init':

(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/crtendS.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'
vs.o:(.dtors+0x4): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: error in vs.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

*

What could be the problem? (Thanks for stopping by :))

Comment: Might help if you post your code? Although even if you do I'm not the person to help you. Not an expert on embedded systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're linking the object files, not just compiling them.

Make sure that you *only* compile the files, don't link them! You do that using the `-c` option. Do not use the `-l` option, you don't want to link anything at this stage. So:

```
gcc -c -o usb_comm.o usb_comm.c
gcc -c -o hex2bin.o hex2bin.c
gcc -c -o hex_read.o hex_read.c
gcc -c -o crc32.o crc32.c
```

(I omitted the `-I` flags to save space here.)

Then finally link all those object files into a shared library, and link against usb-1.0:

```
gcc -shared -o libhello.so usb_comm.o hex2bin.o hex_read.o crc32.o -lusb-1.0
```

You should use a Makefile though for this. Or, even better, use a proper build system, like [CMake](http://www.cmake.org), which is very easy to use. It's provided by all common Linux distros, so simply install it with the package manager (it it's not installed already), and read a quick tutorial on it.

Comment: You might also state what the problem is up-front i.e. that he has both compiled and linked the files with the initial gcc step, which is what is producing the multiple definition error in the last step

Comment: @NikosC. When I tried _ gcc -fPIC -o usb_comm.o usb_comm.c _, and error comes as: ** usb_comm.c:(.text+0x742): undefined reference to hex2bin' usb_comm.c:(.text+0x74e): undefined reference to hex_read' usb_comm.c:(.text+0x7c2): undefined reference to crc32' ** When I tried _ gcc -fPIC -o hex2bin.o hex2bin.c, gcc -fPIC -o hex_read.o hex_read.c, gcc -fPIC -o crc32.o crc32.c _ error is ** (.text+0x18): undefined reference to main' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status **

Comment: @NikosC. usb_comm.c is the only main file and others (hex2bin.c, hex_read.c,crc32.c) are used in that

Comment: @NikosC. yeah. It works, but only change was that I used -c in place of all -fPIC

Comment: @NikosC. `-fPIC` only says to compile position independent code - this is not necessarily required for atmel (I know it's needed for x64 and sparcv9, but not always required for i386 and 32bit sparc), it's the `-c` option that compiles only, without linking

Comment: @vineeshvs @Petesh: Weird. I mentioned the `-c` option in the answer, but then forgot to use it in the example commands. And you're right about fPIC; I didn't actually even notice the atmel tag.